# Mage log is not working in Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, log, error-log

My mage log is not working.

I am using magento 1.9. I am also using **wamp** server so permission issues should not arise for the `var` folder.

I first went to  **System > Configuration > Developer** and switch on logging

I then placed the following Mage log at this location:

**app\Mage.php**

```
 public static function run($code = '', $type = 'store', $options = array())
 {
    Mage::log('work');
    Mage::log('My log entry', null, 'mylogfile.log');
 }
```

I then refreshed my home page but nothing came up with the log files.

Is there something that I am missing?

I checked the permssions folder for my VAR and its :

```
drwxr-xr-x 1 theSeeker  197609   0 Sep 26 08:49 log/
```

Comment: have you checked permission of var directory ?

Comment: i am using wamp. so permissions should not really be an issue

Comment: please share the screenshot where you enable log in admin

Answer (score 1):

All Mage:: functions work after it has verified it's all required functions are working fine.

It first sets the app root path using **`self::setRoot();`** function.

Then checks for whether Magento is installed or not. Then sets the application config model.

Then it calls the following to initiate the rendering of the store view:

```
self::$_app->run(array(
     'scope_code' => $code,
     'scope_type' => $type,
     'options'    => $options,
));
```

After this complete process, the **`Mage::log()`** function starts working.

In your question, you have removed all default code from the **`function run($code = '', $type = 'store', $options = array())`** function.

Try **`Mage::log()`** after just after:

```
self::$_app->run(array(
     'scope_code' => $code,
     'scope_type' => $type,
     'options'    => $options,
));
```

Comment: If i run https://paste.ofcode.org/37ccujDxcru9uDgYkE2PMiy   my log file name 35 instead of event.log, may i know what is the issue? screenshot -> https://snipboard.io/62r8hA.jpg @Mohit Kumar Arora thanks